# Gmail crashing in Chrome?

Tags: gmail, google-chrome, user-interface

Since the change in Gmail's interface, I've noticed that the Gadgets I use have disappeared. When I tried to expand Gmail's sidebar there were no line with three dots to grab and today I couldn't attach a file, so I tried in Firefox. In Firefox, I found the Gadgets, the line to expand the sidebar and I could attach a file. I've disabled every extension and script in my Chrome but these problems persist.
Someone else is having similar problems?
There's anything I can do to have, at least, my Gadgets again in Chrome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you are using the latest [stable build](http://www.google.com/chrome). The beta version may have issues with certain features. Also I would advise trying to clear your cache and cookies in Chrome and try again and see if the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Browser extensions may be causing the crashes.

I disabled *snip.it* and *yesware* and the crashing stopped.

You might wanna do the same. Just disable extensions that might be related to Gmail.